# Custom ApplicationInsights LogAppender - Log4net

Tags: logging, log4net, application-insights

I have developed a custom log appender to send exceptions to Application Insights.
The problem is that some exceptions show on the AI protal (Azure) but some other exceptions don't.
Anyone had similar problem?

Cheers

Eric

Comment: Please add further details of your custom appender, your configs and any relevant details from the set up of your Application Insights instance.